# Route ASIO input to WDM virtual microphones

Tags: naudio, asio, wdm

I'm doing some sound manipulation with the Dante Virtual Soundcard (DVS).  The software I am using (ffmpeg) can only record from WDM microphones.  DVS has a limitation of 8 stereo channels for WDM, so I'm seeing if I can use the 64 channel ASIO option.

Basically, I am trying to route 64 ASIO input channels to 32 virtual stereo WDM microphones.  I would then initiate ffmpeg recordings of these 32 WDM microphones as different times depending on which microphones are used.

NAudio's patchbay example (https://github.com/markheath/naudio-asio-patchbay) was a good start but routes to ASIO outputs.  Is it possible to route to multiple WaveIn devices?